# Using Angular 1.2 and Animate.css for loading animation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate, animate.css

I'm trying to get a page to animate in on load using Angular 1.2 and Animate.css.

Here's the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oDiDfRCO2Msc0StNrtqH

I'd like the background to crossfade in and the yellow menu on the right side to slide in from the right.

In main.html:

```
<div>
  <div class="background-container">
    <my-Background></my-Background>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-container">
      <my-Menu id="menu"></my-Menu>
  </div>

</div>
```

In main.css:

```
.menu-container.ng-enter {
    animation:3s fadeInRightBig;
}


.background-container.ng-enter {
    animation:3s fadeInDown;
}
```

The animations defined in main.css don't seem to get fired. I'm pretty sure its due to the order and/or timing of css being loaded although I might be dealing with more than one issue.

What's the "right" way to ensure everything, from an animation standpoint, is loaded and ready in order to make the animations work on load?

Comment: Have you tried using the `animated` class? `<div class="animated fadeInDown background-container">` ... and `<div class="animated fadeInRightBig menu-container">`

Comment: There is also the [ngFx](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ngFx) module which is Animate.css for angular.

Comment: @mobabur94 I'll look into ngFx, it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like an HTML5 loader to load your initial assets when the DOM is loaded.  There is a jQuery plugin, I know it is not Angular and another library, but it may help your order of operation.

http://gianlucaguarini.github.io/jquery.html5loader/

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that but as you point out I'm really looking for the correct "angular way" to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try nganimate , an easy documentation for you to refer
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate